# Axiomatic string theory?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, string-theory

There have been many proposal of a mathematical definition of Quantum Field Theory, for instance through [Wightman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wightman_axioms) or [Osterwalder-Schrader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_function#Osterwalder%E2%80%93Schrader_axioms) axioms. Were there any efforts toward doing the same for String theory?

Comment: No, string theory is not a "theory" based on a set of rules that may then be defined axiomatically. In that sense it is altogether different from quantum field theory.

Comment: QFT is a part of mathematics produced mostly by mathematicians  while String Theory is not. Various people produce results which are thought to belong to ST, but these are just individual results.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Could you elaborate a little why this is so?

Comment: @markvs Surely the standard model and what all those people do at CERN is physics‽ There are some very special examples of QFTs (non-interacting, topological, conformal, ...) that have become part of mathematics, but QFT is certainly physics. In fact, one could argue the opposite of what you say: QFT has produced experimentally testable predictions; afaik, if anything, string theory has so far produced more mathematics than any real physics (I do not know if applications of AdS/CFT to the quark-gluon plasma or condensed matter theory produced new results that can be tested by experiments)

Comment: In CERN, they discovered Higgs boson, which is indeed, a confirmation of some mathematical result. But math part of ST is just a union of disjoint facts unlike QFT, IMHO.